# Удаление объекта через клавишу на клавиатуре

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу удалять монету, когда буду находиться на ней, но при условии, что я нажал определённую клавишу. Если я просто буду удалять монету, когда колайдер игрока зайдёт на колайдер монеты, всё нормально, и она удаляется, но у меня не получается реализовать удаление при нажатии.

```
if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: GetKeyDown - срабатывает единоразово в Update. Попробуй GetKey https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Comment: Решение. Создаём `GameObject Money` и булевую переменную `isColl = false`. Когда игрок заходит в колладейр монеты мы создаём ссылку на объект этой монеты `Money = coll.gameobject` и присваиваем переменной isColl значение true, а если игрок вышел из коллайдера то значение false. После чего в апдейте проверяем, если мы нажали на нужную нам кнопку и isColl равен true. тогда удаляем объект Money. `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B) && isColl){Destroy(Money);}`